# Does Proverbs 16:9 say that God has determined every move mankind makes?

Tags: proverbs

> "A man's heart deviseth (**יחשב: considers, thinks about**) his way: but YHVH directeth (**יכין: establishes, sets up, appoints**) his steps. Proverbs 16:9

Does Proverbs 16:9 say that God has determined every move mankind makes?

Comment: Please note that not all of your readers consider themselves bound by the Biblical texts. For this reason we generally try to avoid using first person plural language on this site. For more on that, see [Friends, we are not Christian](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/441/3555) and [this explanation of common misconceptions about the site](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/803/3555).

Comment: Thank you @Susan. I wasn't aware of this. I edited the question. Is this more acceptable for this site?

Comment: No, Gd made man like coffee machine,  which type you want you decide but Gd knows but doesn't determine

Comment: I'm sorry @user12422, I'm having trouble understanding what you mean. Are you saying a coffee machine decides for itself what type it wants to be? Or are you saying God decides the type, but doesn't determine what the coffee machine does? Because a coffee machine can't do anything until somebody presses the "On" button, and then it does exactly what it was made to do. Maybe I'm just misunderstanding.

Comment: Gd created the machine and all options but you decide which button to press,  how hard it is to understand?  If he created the machine and presses buttons himself why are we here then?  Just to be manipulated?

Comment: Hey @user12422. I'm sorry, I don't understand your anology. How can a coffee machine decide which of it's own buttons to push? Ecclesiastes explains the meaning of life very well, and Genesis 1:26 and Isaiah 45:23 explain God's purpose. We're not allowed to have discussions in the comments, but if you would provide an answer below with your interpretation of this verse, that would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not only every move mankind makes but all things within His creation as described in Romans 11:36 - "For from him and through him and to him are all things. To him be glory forever. Amen." From God, through God, and to God . . . all things." And yes, this includes things that we humans see and experience as evil. I would have to staunchly agree with Dr. R.C. Sproul that "if there is one maverick molecule in the universe, then God is not God."

Comment: Thank you Jack. I don't agree with a lot of what Sproul said, but I like this. It sounds similar to Louis de Broglie's Pilot Wave interpretation of Quantum Mechanics.

Comment: God is ultimately in control of every molecule, but that doesn't mean that He doesn't afford living beings (especially humans) the freedom to choose.